# Does anyone know how to style a the PopUp for EditMode="PopUp" in Telerik RadGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I've got a RadGrid in place and I've got my MasterTableView's EditMode set to PopUp.

I was wondering if there is a way to style the default input PopUp? I have considered just creating my own template and using it inline but I like the default PopUp. I would like to be able to modify the background color and maybe the text.

I have checked the documentation but the closest thing I could find to modifying the PopUp was the position when it is opened.

Comment: It seems the best a way to do this is to instead use a RadWindow and then modifying those properties. 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better doing it by RadWindow. You can definitely achieve this by overriding CSS style of Telerik Edit Form.

### HERE IS THE STYLE

```
.rgEditForm table {
/*CHANGE FONTS*/
font: normal 13px 'Your Font',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important;
line-height: 22px !important;

/*CHANGE BACKGROUD - FACEBOOK'S BLUE*/
background-color: #3B5999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I ended up using RadWindow as a solution and then passing the parameters to a from. Good to know though for future use. Thank you.